# TestFlight takeoff blocks my app's main thread in poor network situation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, testflight

As it is required in TestFlight's documentation, I put **[TestFlight takeoff:]** in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions.
```

It works just fine except that if my app is launched in very poor network situation, after the app enters background and re-enter foreground, it will freeze for around 10 seconds and then become responsible to user action again.

If I remove the takeoff calling, my app works just fine.
Is this a bug of TestFlight? How can I handle it?

Jianbin LIN